# How to get a msgbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I am creating a simple enquiry form with upload option.

If I click submit button it goes to another page and displays success message but it should come in the same page as a message box.  What should I do?

Here is my Html code:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Name</span>
        <input name="name" type="text" size="25" class="text1" />
    </li>
    <li><span>Contact</span>
        <input name="contact" type="text" size="25" class="text2" />
    </li>
    <li><span>E-mail</span>
        <input name="email" type="text" size="25" class="text3" />
    </li>
    <li><span>Subject</span>
        <input name="subject" type="text" size="25" class="text4" />
    </li>
    <li><span>Message</span>
        <textarea name="message" size="250" class="text5"></textarea>
    </li>
</ul>
<label for="upload"></label>
<div class="x">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="file" class="button">
</div>
<div class="x1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</div>
```

And this is my PHP code for uploading and inserting:

```
<?php
$target = "upload/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$ok = 1;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {
    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }    
?>
<?php
include ("conn.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $sql="insert into cform  (name,contact,email,subject,message,upload)values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['contact']."','".$_    POST['email']."','".$_POST['subject']."','".$_POST['message']."','$target')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result)
        {
        echo "could not enter data";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "successfuly entered";
        }
    }    
?>
```

This PHP page has to run in background and when I click the submit button a message box should display success.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(! $result) {
     $msg = "could not enter data";
    }else{
       $msg = "successfuly entered";
     }
     header('Location: http://www.example.com/form.php?message=$msg');
    //Redirect to form page with set message.
```

add script in form page to display message

```
 if(isset($_GET['message'])){
    print $_GET['message'];
  }
```

This solution for as per your code
And another option is using ajax.

Comment: Thanks for ur help let me try

Answer (score 2):

Edit the echo portion of the page as

**second page**

```
$rspnse = "";
if(!$result){
  $rspnse = "Error";
}
else{
  $rspnse = "Success";
}
header('Location: previous_page.php?response='.$rspnse);
```

*Replace the `previous_page.php` with your original `url` of the first page*

**first page**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['response'])){
?>
<script>
alert('<?php echo $_GET['response'] ?>');
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: i gave a try for this but it gives warning like this
**Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Raj\cform\upload_file.php:2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raj\cform\upload_file.php on line 29**

Comment: remove any kind of echo you have in the second page. header will not be sent if the page contains any print/echo statements..

Comment: remove the echo statements from your file uploading block.. i think they are creating the problem.

Comment: Still it occurs **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Raj\cform\upload_file.php:2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raj\cform\upload_file.php on line 29**

Comment: is the data getting inserted in ur database?? I see from your code that your sql query is inside quotes...